# How to read, modify structs from a non-text file?

Tags: c, struct, file-io

I want to save some struct into a file and read all of them or modify them. I tried like this, but this way I got only the last saved structs, and I don't know how to get all of them, or how to modify them later in the file.

I don't get any error just the last saved structs, but in the file I see all of them if I open with a text editor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MAX_STRING_LEN 80
#define PHONE_NUMBER 15

struct order {
    time_t   systime;
    char     name[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    char     email[MAX_STRING_LEN];
    int      phonenumber;
    int      size;
};


//functions
void saveToFiles(struct order *current);
void dbList(struct order *current);

//save into file
void saveToFiles(struct order *current) {
    FILE * file=fopen("db.txt", "a");
    if(file != NULL) {
        fwrite(current, sizeof(struct order), 1, file);
        //      fwrite("\n", sizeof("\n"), 1, file);   //If I broke the line then all of the reading get some numbers, without any meaning
        fclose(file);
    }
}

//list the db
void dbList(struct order *current) {
    int option;
    printf("list: \n    1 - ful list\n    2 - just names\n    3 - just size\n    0 - exit");
    scanf(" %i", &option);
    if(option == 0) {
        exit(1);
    }
    if(option == 1) {
        //loadList(1);
        struct order *obj=malloc(sizeof(struct order));
        FILE * file = fopen("db.txt","rb");
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);  //I tried to put the file read at the begining of the file
        while(fread(obj, sizeof(struct order), 1, file)) {
            printf("LOG: op1\n");
            fread(obj, sizeof(struct order), 1, file);
            printf("%s/%s/%d/%d\n", obj->name, obj->email, obj->phonenumber, obj->size);
        }
        if(feof(file)) {
            printf("\n--END--\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Some error...");
        }
    }
}

//***

int main(k)
{
    struct order current;   //struct init
    //    current = malloc(sizof(*current));

    int option = 1;
    while(option != 0) {
        printf(" " "\x1B[34m");
        printf("0 exit \n 1 new \n 2 list \n \n " "\x1B[0m");
        scanf(" %i", &option);
        if(option == 1) {
            getNewOrder(&current);
        }
        if(option == 2) {
            dbList(&current);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You `fread` twice: Once in the `while` condition, then again in the body of that loop. Each read "consumes" data. Get rid of the `fread` in the loop body.

Comment: @MOehm oh, true, thanks, could you help me how can I modify the saved structs?

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to load the database, make the changes, then save it again. (I take it your database is small.) Fiddling with data in the file is tricky. For example, what are you going to do if you want to remove a record in the middle?

Comment: @MOehm This is my problem, I thought, than I have to delete the record and after that copy the rest at one place ahead? But If you say better to copy all into the memory and then overwrite the file than I should try that way.

Comment: @MOehm If you write this into an answer then I can accept to you. Thank your time.

Comment: Also note, while it is perfectly fine to write a struct to a file using fwrite and then read those structs back into a file ***on the same compiler/machine*** it is not a portable way to store and retrieve struct information across different platforms or compilers due to potential differences in struct padding on each. Which is why data written to file is generally *serialized* to avoid any of the struct padding issues.

Answer (score 0):

For write file, pls check if fseek() to SEEK_END and then do fwrite can help.